# bxslider load jQuery on specific slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have BXSlider (https://bxslider.com/) installed. Now I want the following jQuery script to run on entering a "slide".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".next-prev-nav").fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
  $(".disable-slide-nav").hide();
});
```

(The script enables the navigation of the slider again.)

I tried to search the website of BXslider, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Look into `onSliderLoad` callback method

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for either `onSlideBefore` *(executes immediately before each slide transition)* or `onSlideAfter` *(executes immediately after each slide transition - when transition completes)* depending on your needs both can be found [here](https://bxslider.com/options/) - look at the section `Callbacks`.

Here is an example:

```js
$(function(){
  var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    captions: true,
    slideWidth: 600,
    auto: true,
    pause: 1000,
    onSlideBefore: function () {
      console.log('onSlideBefore');
      // Your code either goes here or...
    },
    onSlideAfter: function () {
      console.log('onSlideAfter');
      // Goes here...
      // For example lets turn the slider off after the second slide appears
      slider.stopAuto();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<div class="bxslider">
  <div><img src="https://bxslider.com/assets/images/coffee1.jpg" title="Funky roots"></div>
  <div><img src="https://bxslider.com/assets/images/coffee2.jpg" title="The long and winding road"></div>
  <div><img src="https://bxslider.com/assets/images/coffee3.jpg" title="Happy trees"></div>
</div>
```